# Creating a transaction with node-pg and Express

Tags: node.js, api, express.js, postgresql

I'm trying to write a `TRANSACTION` with `node-postgres` in an Express API. [The code below works as it's supposed to, mostly looking for what should be corrected/changed]

This would be a `POST` request that creates a "transaction" and updates a record in a separate table. So basically a couple of queries at once. Below is the code:

For context, `db` is a connection pool to a postgres db.

```js
// @desc        Add a Transaction
// @route       DELETE /api/v1/envelopes/:id/transactions
exports.addEnvelopeTransaction = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { title, amount } = req.body;
    const date = new Date();

    const envelopeQuery  = "SELECT * FROM envelopes WHERE envelopes.id = $1";
    const transactionQuery = "INSERT INTO transactions(title, amount, date, envelope_id)VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *";
    const updateEnvQuery = "UPDATE envelopes SET budget = budget - $1 WHERE id = $2 RETURNING *";

  try {
        // Use SQL TRANSACTION
        await db.query('BEGIN');
        const envelope = await db.query(envelopeQuery, [id])
        if (envelope.rowCount < 1) {
      return res.status(404).send({
        message: "No envelope information found",
            });
        };
        const newTransaction = await db.query(transactionQuery, [title, amount, date, id]);
        await db.query(updateEnvQuery, [amount, id]);
        await db.query('COMMIT');
        res.status(201).send({
            status: 'Success',
            message: 'New transaction created',
            data: newTransaction.rows[0],
            });
  } catch (err) {
        await db.query('ROLLBACK');
    return res.status(500).send({
            error: err.message
        });
  }
};
```

I smell some bad code here, I can't really tell if I'm using `BEGIN`, `COMMIT`, and `ROLLBACK` in the appropriate places.

What should I change?